# Decode the message

Tags: cipher

Try to decode this message:

> y08 700) 07734

1. Hint:

   > You don't need a common method to 
   > decode
2. Hint

   > You need a calculator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is

> hELLO COOL BO(y)
>  Although I'm not sure about the "y"

Reasoning

> This is roughly how it looks if you type it into a calculator and turn it upside down.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess:

> HELLO COOL BOY

Explanation:

> Put it on a 7-segment display and turn it upside down. However, the upside-down "y" is throwing me off as that obviously isn't a "y" upside-down.